# 2 Right Outer Join in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, outer-join

I have an issue in understanding a very simple yet interesting query concerning 2 right outer joins with 'non-sequential' on-expressions.  Here is the query:

```
select * from C 
right outer join A on A.F1 = C.F1 
right outer join B on B.F1 = C.F1;
```

Here are the tables:

```
create table A ( F1 varchar(200)); 
create table B ( F1 varchar(200)); 
create table C ( F1 varchar(200));
```

Here are some rows:

```
insert into A values ('A'); 
insert into A values ('B');
insert into A values ('C');
insert into B values ('B'); 
insert into B values ('C');
insert into B values ('D');
insert into C values ('A'); 
insert into C values ('C'); 
insert into C values ('D');
```

Note: The query **select * from C right outer join A on A.F1 = C.F1 right outer join B on B.F1 = C.F1;** join expressions both refers to table C.

The query returns (in columns then rows)

```
(NULL,NULL, B),(C, C, C).(NULL, **NULL**, D)
```

and I expected (in my little understanding of SQL)

```
(NULL,NULL, B),(C, C, C),(NULL, **D**, D)
```

What is the logical sequence whereby SQL (tested on Microsoft SQL as well as MySQL) get to these values.

In my "execution" sequence I sit with on table A values of A, null (for B), C, null (for D) and in Table B, null (for A), B, C, D before the "product" is amalgamated with C (B,C,D).

Gawie
PS: I have test this using MySQL as well as Microsoft SQL 2008... with the same results.

Comment: "Brain no work good sleep without."  Ouch, my poor brain.

Comment: Agree, Would've been clearer to name the tables different from the column values.  How about T1, T2 and T3.

Answer (score 1):

There's no D value in table "A" to join to, which is why it returns NULL instead of the D you expect.  It's easier to see when you identify which table the value is coming from via column alias:

```
SELECT c.f1 AS c, a.f1 AS a, b.f1 AS b 
  FROM c 
RIGHT JOIN A on A.F1 = C.F1 
RIGHT JOIN B on B.F1 = C.F1
```

Comment: Any `D` value from table `C` would have to survive the right join to table `A`

Answer (score 0):

Table A doesn't contain a field 'D', so there's no way that D can appear in the second column in the result set, Gawie.  The fields in the result set will be C.F1, A.F1, B.F1 (in the same order that the tables appear in the joins).

Answer (score 0):

Right joins are evaluated in the order in which they appear (from left to right.) Let's start with `from C`:

```
C        -->  (A), (C), (D)
```

Then `right join A`, joining on `A.F1 = C.F1`:

```
C, A     -->  (A, A), (NULL, B), (C, C)
```

Then `right join B` (matching the first column, since the join is on `B.F1 = C.F1`):

```
C, A, B  -->  (NULL, NULL, B), (C, C, C), (NULL, NULL, D)
```

So because `from C right join A` does not contain an D in the first column, the `right join B` fails to match, and appends a row containing NULL for the column from C and A, and `D` for the column from B.

Comment: Order doesn't matter - it's the criteria between the tables.  A and B only relate to C, so the query has to return values that exist with respect to C to A or C to B.  Hence, C to B with no match in A will return NULL from A

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Order does matter.  If you swap the joins, the result will be: `(null, null, A), (NULL, NULL, B), (C, C, C)`

Answer (score 0):

C, A     -->  (A, A), (NULL, B), (C, C)

Then right join B (matching the first column, since the join is on B.F1 = C.F1):

C, A, B  -->  (NULL, NULL, B), (C, C, C), (NULL, NULL, D)

This is where I get lost...

Why is C, A, B not equal to (NULL, B, B), ... etc

for C, A for column B equals (NULL, B)
right outer join (NULL, B) with B should yield (NULL, B, B)... unless the matching is reversed!
C, A, B --> (NULL, B, B)  (which is obviously wrong - just don't completely understand why)

Comment: In other words - is the login not [NULL OUTER JOIN B] giving B hence NULL, B, B?

Comment: In other words - how does the value of A change when we are joining B and C!?

Comment: The reason `(NULL, B)` is not equal to (`B`) is that it's matching on the first column, which happens to be NULL.  If you change the `on` condition from `B.F1 = C.F1` to `B.F1 = A.F1`, it would match on the second column.

Comment: Andomar - you're a star!!  Thanks.  Gawie

Comment: Why is it matching on the first column - the SQL reads C right outer join A - which means null right outer join B, which should yield B and not null?